# Typescript type is not assignable to type : Error while re-assigning item

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, types

I am trying to implement functionality where once the button is clicked, it hides it from the list and deselects the corresponding check-box from the hierarchy structure(TreeNode) on the left.

Rightside.component.html :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <ul class="selection-list">
    <li *ngFor="let item of getSelections()">
      <button class="btn" (click)="deselect(item)" *ngIf="item.selected">
        <i class="fa fa-close"> {{ item.displayName }} </i>
      </button> 
    </li>
  </ul>
```

rightside.component.ts:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../../shared/service/data.service';
import { TreeNode } from '../../shared/dto/TreeNode';

import html from './rightside.component.html';
import css from './rightside.component.css';

@Component({
  selector: 'rightside-component',
  template: html,
  providers: [DataService],
  styles: [css],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})

export class RightSideComponent implements OnInit {
  selections: string[];
  @Input() treeNode: TreeNode<string>[];

  constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  getSelections() : TreeNode<string>[] {
    if (typeof(this.treeNode) == "undefined" || (this.treeNode) === null) {
      return [];
    }
    return this.treeNode;
  }

  deselect(item: TreeNode<string>): void {
    if((item.children) !== null) {
      item.children.forEach(element => {
        this.deselect(element);
      });
    }
    item.selected = false;
  }

}
```

productline.component.html:

```
<p>Productlines</p>
<mat-input-container>
    <input #searchInput matInput placeholder="Search for Product Line">
</mat-input-container>
<div class="flex-container">
<div class="PLCheck" *ngIf="isDataLoaded">
    <fortune-select
       (dataChanged)="onDataChange($event)"
       [searchTerm]="searchInput.value"
       [currentNode]="tree"
       [singleSelect]="singleSelect"
       [collapsed]="true"></fortune-select>
</div>
<div class="sendToRight">
    <rightside-component
        [treeNode]="selectedProductLine">
    </rightside-component>
</div>
</div>
```

Treenode.ts :

```
import { ValidationService } from '../service/validation.service';

export class TreeNode<T> {
  displayName:   string;
  children:      TreeNode<T>[];
  selected:      boolean;
  collapsed?:    boolean;
  indeterminate: boolean;
  selectable:    boolean;
  value:         T;

  public static getAllNodeValues<T>(tree: TreeNode<T>):T[] {
    return TreeNode.getAllCheckedNodes<T>(tree).map((nodes:TreeNode<T>) => nodes.value);
  }

  public static getTopLevelNodeValues<T>(tree: TreeNode<T>):T[] {
    return TreeNode.getTopLevelCheckedNodes<T>(tree).map((nodes:TreeNode<T>) => nodes.value);
  }

  public static getTopLevelCheckedNodes<T>(tree: TreeNode<T>):TreeNode<T>[] {
    if(tree.selected) {
      return [tree];
    } else if(tree.indeterminate) {
      return tree.children.reduce(
        (acc,child) => acc.concat(TreeNode.getTopLevelCheckedNodes(child)),[]);
    } else {
      return <TreeNode<T>[]>[];
    }
  }

  public static getAllCheckedNodes<T>(tree: TreeNode<T>):TreeNode<T>[] {
    if(tree.selected && tree.children) {
      return tree.children.reduce(
        (acc,child) => acc.concat(TreeNode.getAllCheckedNodes(child)),[tree]);
    } else if (tree.selected) {
      return [tree];
    } else if(tree.children) {
      return tree.children.reduce(
        (acc,child) => acc.concat(TreeNode.getAllCheckedNodes(child)),[]);
    } else {
      return <TreeNode<T>[]>[];
    }
  }

  public getValue(): T {
    return this.value;
  }

  public matches(searchTerm:string):boolean {
    if(this.displayName.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())) {
      return true;
    }
    if (!ValidationService.isEmptyList(this.children)) {
      return this.children.some((child) => child.matches(searchTerm));
    }
    return false;
  }

  public selectChildren(selected:boolean):void {
    if (!ValidationService.isEmptyList(this.children)) {
      this.children.map((child) => {
        child.selected = selected;
        child.indeterminate = false;
        child.selectChildren(selected);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

The issue I am facing:

When I click on any button to hide, I have to click multiple times (on the other part of the screen too) before it gets hidden. However, if I start from the bottom-most button and go to the top, it works with a single click.

In order to resolve this, I tried to reassign item by changing:

`item.selected = false;`

to

`item = {...item, selected: false};`

However, then I got the error :

Type '{ selected: false; displayName: string; children: TreeNode[]; collapsed?: boolean; indete...' is not assignable to type 'TreeNode'. Property 'getValue' is missing in type '{ selected: false; displayName: string; children: TreeNode[]; collapsed?: boolean; indete...'.

Is there a way to fix it? How can I get the button hiding to work with a single click, even when clicked in any random order?

EDIT 1:

```
children : (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
collapsed : true
displayName : "Consumer - A1"
getValue : ƒ ()
indeterminate : false
matches : ƒ (searchTerm)
selectChildren : ƒ (selected)
selectable : true
selected : true
value : "A1"
```

When you expand children in above json (there are 5 sub-nodes in the hierarchy) :

```
0:{value: "A2", displayName: "Con - A2", selectable: true, selected: true, children: Array(3), …}
1:{value: "A3", displayName: "H - A3", selectable: true, selected: true, children: Array(2), …}
2:{value: "A4", displayName: "Phy - A4", selectable: true, selected: true, children: Array(4), …}
3:{value: "A5", displayName: "S - A5", selectable: true, selected: true, children: Array(6), …}
4:{value: "0000", displayName: "Unspecified - 0000", selectable: true, selected: true, children: Array(0), …}
```

These nodes further have children.

EDIT 2:

It works when I modify the css from :

```
.selection-list {
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  line-height: 15px;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #555;
  padding-left: 23px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

to

```
.selection-list {
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  line-height: 15px;
  color: #555;
  padding-left: 23px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

The "font-size" tag was somehow causing the issue. Any inputs on what could have been the reason behind this?

Comment: Can you edit your question to let us know an example JSON of what `getSelections` returns please? That way, we can reproduce the issue on our machines

Comment: @user184994 - I have updated the question and added an example JSON. The treeNode structure is a hierarchical structure. When I click on a check-box in the tree, it shows what I have selected on the right-side. If I want to delete it, I can click on the right-side object and it gets de-selected from the tree. This is working, the only problem is that, multiple clicks are being needed for this deselection and the button hiding to take place.

Comment: Can you create a reproduction of the issue in StackBlitz? I've tried to create a reproduction,  but it seems to deselect on the first click https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ikt5p3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: @user184994 - I have posted the code here https://angular-uuty1w.stackblitz.io  There are many dependent files, hence I could not post all of it. So, it has not been reproduced. I think the main problem must be with the "item.selected = false" statement?

Comment: You don't need to post every one of the files, or even every one of the functions. It just needs to be the least amount of code necessary to reproduce the problem. I used `item.selected = false` in the example I posted above, and it worked.

Comment: @user184994 -Could you try adding more levels to the JSON? I'll try to do that as well in my StackBlitz code.

Comment: Can you give a JSON example then please? (Bear in mind the bit you posted earlier is not valid JSON, you'll need to call `JSON.stringify` on the item first)

Comment: @user184994 - I have added the JSON in this example : https://angular-vknapy.stackblitz.io . It works fine without the "selection-list" css. But once I add that, it does not work efficiently with a single click when chosen in a random order. It works from bottom to top with single clicks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177976/discussion-between-tee-jay-and-user184994).